Customize the error message shown when vue3datepicker is set as required and not input provided
I have a vue3datepicker component which is set as required in a form. When I do not select a date and click on submit I get the message "Please fill out this field", which is the default html message as shown below.

I would like to customize this and provide an error message below the datepicker field.
I tried to use the events mentioned in the document, but I couldn't find a solution.
[https://vue3datepicker.com/methods-and-events/events/][2]

that's default form validation bevaiour. you can use additinal package like vee-validate to customize validation logic/messages etc

either use one of the popular validation libraries out there, or add the attribute novalidate to your form which will disable default validation so you can implement your own custom validation.
